# system.windows.interactivity.dll

Tags: wpf, resources

I would like to know, if there is any way to know, what resources system.windows.interactivity.dll are loading?
This dll has a number of folders, containing single file: System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll, and I want to discover, what file is loaded during run time. How could it be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Process Explorer utility tool to get the snapshot of assemblies and their resources loaded in memory. You can download it from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)

Comment: I have tried this already. I see the System.Windows.Interactivity.dll in the list, but I didn't find any way to discover what resources.dll it is using.